# How to create cron job that will run every month on second tuesday

Tags: unix, cron, cron-task

I want to create cron jab that will run on every month on second tuesday. I created a cron job but I am not sure it is correct. Kinldy help me.

```
*    0     *    */1    2       test.sh
```

Comment: might be helpful: https://crontab.guru/

Answer (score 2):

pretty simple solution:

```
30 10 8-14 * 2
```

This is going to run the scripts only once per month on the second Tuesday of that month at 10:30 AM. Should run for any cron and Jenkins "Build periodically" option as well.

Comment: Good one! second Tuesday will fall only on the date range: 8th-14th